# What kind of pixel defection is this? Can it be fixed?

Tags: display, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

I recently purchased a monitor which unfortunately comes with a very strange defective pixel. However, I also came across a very old post which describe the symptoms perfectly, though sadly with no solution.

[Dead or stuck pixel? Weird pixel behavior](https://superuser.com/q/1140325)

I apologize if this post is inappropriate in some manners, but I'm very desperate at this point.

Comment: If you recently purchased it you can RMA it... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization I doubt we can fix hardware issues by giving you advice. You can use a Live operating system to confirm it is a hardware and not a software issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD

Comment: Every manufacturer of monitors has a dead pixel policy, you need to see what it is before attempting an RMA, if it was bought at a retail store, simply return it for a refund.

Comment: If you have the *exact* same issue then it is likely a column access defect in the LCD pixel array. That it lights up blue *only* when other in that column are powered suggest that the "row select"  for that colour on that pixel is stuck on and when the column is selected then the pixel ends up on. It is a hardware defect and there is likely nothing you can do about it. Contact your supplier and find out if they have a policy on dead pixels. Some manufacturers and suppliers consider "some" stuck pixels to be acceptable. If you are truly desperate then contact your supplier.

Comment: @Moab YMMV but I have returned a screen that was deemed acceptable under their dead pixel policy and I got my money back. Arguing with me would've cost them more money probably.

Comment: Of course all this only applies if the monitor was purchased new, not second-hand.

Comment: @Mokubai Can you add that info to the other thread too? Thanks.

Comment: @Mokubai returning is not an option. is there something I can try before giving up entirely?

Comment: I do not believe so. From my understanding this is a physical defect in the actual subpixel wiring *at that actual pixel*. It is not something that can be fixed by software, and trying to get close enough to the pixel wiring would mean the destruction of everything holding the screen together.